# Vue JS Vuetify $emit is not working on first time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have two components

1. Dish component
2. Dish Update component

In the Dish component I imported the Dish Update component like this

```html
<template>
  <v-layout row wrap>

   <v-btn @click="modalShow({name:'pizza'})"></v-btn>
    <!--Update Modal -->
    <v-dialog v-model="updateDisplay" max-width="80%">
      <update-dish></update-dish>
    </v-dialog>
    <!--Modal -->
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

This is my `modalShow` function. It takes a `dish` object and passes it to the Dish Update component through `emit`.

```
 async modalShow(dish) {
   this.$root.$emit("dish", dish);
   this.updateDisplay = true;
 }
```

In the Dish Update component I get data in the `mounted` life cycle hook:

```
mounted() {       
  this.$root.$on("dish", dish => {
    this.name = dish.name;
  }
```

This is not working in the first click: it doesn't pass data to the update component.

After the first click when I click it again it works. Why could this happen?

It worked before I upgraded my vuetify version from 1.5 to 2.2.4.

Comment: why async modalShow() ?

Comment: event without async result still the same

Comment: please paste the template portion of the component code as well as the script portion for all the cases you have mentioned here for clarity sake. The error might be else where in your code base

Answer (score 0):

You can try using @click.native

```
<template>
  <v-layout row wrap>

   <v-btn @click.native="modalShow({name:'pizza'})"></v-btn>
    <!--Update Modal -->
    <v-dialog v-model="updateDisplay" max-width="80%">
      <update-dish></update-dish>
    </v-dialog>
    <!--Modal -->
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

As this is a known issue, you can see on vuetify github

Comment: What would be the reason for preventing the event default, I'm unsure as to why that would help in this situation, if the modalShow function is being called successfully, why does it matter about the event?

Comment: I have changes my answer but I firstly used e.preventDefault() as may be vuetify v-btn adding some behaviour on click as this is not a normal html button

Comment: Thanks, seems like a reasonable assumption you made there